# Is `==` still called the "abstract equality operator"?

Tags: javascript

`==` used to be called the abstract equality operator, and its [abstract equality comparison algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) was defined in the ECMAScript specification.

This algorithm is now named [IsLooselyEqual](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal) in the specification, and the term "abstract equality" is no longer used in the specification.

Has the operator been renamed?

Comment: Yes, we call it `equal equal`. And `===` is `exactly equal equal`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is not related with code, but with used terminology

Comment: This is trivially related to code.

Comment: @Justinas I’ve never heard `===` being referred to as “exactly equal equal”. The spec also doesn’t refer to it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* call `==` the abstract equality operator because it checks according to the abstract equality comparison algorithm. So, this is a valid, if unofficial, name for it.

The more popular name for this is "loose equality". Also an unofficial name. It is opposed to "strict equality" with `===`.

---

The operator is simply referred to "the equals operator" in [ECMAScript 5](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.1).

In ECMAScript 6 the specification has an umbrella [12.10 Equality Operators](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-equality-operators) section which groups together `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==`. However, parts of the specification do still mention "the equality operator" like [12.10.3 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) which reads the following at the end of the section:

> NOTE 2 The equality operators maintain the following invariants:
>
> - `A != B` is equivalent to `!(A == B)`.
> - `A == B` is equivalent to `B == A`, except in the order of evaluation of `A` and `B`.
>
> NOTE 3 The equality operator is not always transitive. For example, there might be two distinct String objects, each representing the same String value; each String object would be considered equal to the String value by the `==` operator, but the two String objects would not be equal to each other. For example:
>
> - `new String("a") == "a"` and `"a" == new String("a")` are both `true`.
> - `new String("a") == new String("a")` is `false`.

This is still the case in the latest official ECMAScript 12 (2021) specification. The relevant section is [13.11 Equality Operators](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-equality-operators) which still contains `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==`. The end of [13.11.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) still contains the same notes as ECMAScript 6 did.

---

Therefore the *operator* is "the equality operator*. The *operation* it performs is called the [Abstract Equality Comparison in ECMAScript 12](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) (with an analogous "Strict Equality Comparison" for `===`) and recently has been renamed to [IsLooselyEqual](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal) (with an analogous "IsStrictlyEqual") in the latest (2022) draft.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 5, the `==` operator was called the "[equals operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.1)", and `===` was called the "[strict equals operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.4)".

In ES2022, the term "[equality operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-equality-operators)" is used to encompass both (and the word-pairing "equals operator" does not occur).

The term "loose equality operator" does not appear in ES2022, although the algorithm used to define its behavior is called [`IsLooselyEqual`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal).

The term "strict equality operator" does not appear in ES2022, although the algorithm used to define its behavior is called [`IsStrictlyEqual`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isstrictlyequal).

On this basis, I would say `==` was never* officially called the "abstract equality operator". It was the "equals operator". However, given that *this* term is no longer used in the specification, perhaps its name has changed to the "equality operator" or possibly the "loose equality operator" (with the converse being the "strict equality operator").

*need to check prior to ES5

Comment: "**need to check prior to ES5*" - [ES1](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_1st_edition_june_1997.pdf) only has "equality operator" (check section "11.9 Equality operators" page 46 of the spec/page 58 of the PDF). There is no strict equality yet. [ES2](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_2nd_edition_august_1998.pdf) is the same - page 50 of the spec. [ES3](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_3rd_edition_december_1999.pdf) introduces strict equality and still just the equals operator. Page 55 of the spec.

Comment: And for reference, past specs are published [on this page by ECMA international](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/)